# Is it possible to strenghten a part of a magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Magnets's atoms are vital for the strength of its magnets. The magnetic fields are the most crowded at the pole of the magnets which is the reason why the poles have the maximum magnetic attraction.

Suppose we imagine a small button magnet and keep it on one of its faces. So, is it possible that we can adjust a its atoms in such a way that that half of the face exerts a weaker (less no. of magnetic fields) and the other half exerts its original amount of magnetic force (if not more).

> So, is such a magnet possible to synthesize? Is there any way at all to affect the magnetic force of attraction of a certain portion?

#### Possible solution:-

I had read somewhere that some type of material prevents magnetic fields and dampens their force of attraction at the applied portion (Maybe used in the transportation of huge magnets, who knows?). So using that and covering a part of a magnet would serve my purpose. Does anybody know about something like that? or any other way to accomplish my objective?

Comment: If anybody likes the question I posed, and want to know the answer too, could they be so kind as to assign a bounty to it In **case** the question is _not_ answered in *48 Hours?* I may not be able to as I do not have the required repo....

Comment: FWIW: A single, solid piece of ferromagnetic material can be magnetized with multiple pole-pairs:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbach_array

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding#Magnetic_shielding

Comment: This is no different from electrostatics. To strengthen or weaken the field of the permanent magnet, you can use the geometric shape in combination with inserts from materials with high magnetic permeability.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I partially agree, but here that magnetic field will be affected for the pole/face of the magnet, rather I am wanting part of the _face_ of the magnet to change it's strength.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, the second link you provided is really great and is kinda relevant to my question. Lemme dig through it to see if there is any answer there...

Comment: @SolomonSlow Could you just write a paragraph on 'Magnetic Shielding' materials and post it so that I may mark it as the answer and close the question?